# How to feeding a function into another function in R

Tags: r

I want to feed a function into another function in R.

I have a function that I have named R and it has 1 argument which is PD. I want to create a second function called K which will have 2 arguments namely PD and LGD and it will feed the function R into function K

```
R = function(PD) {(0.12*(1-exp(-50*PD))/(1-exp(-50)) + 0.24*(1-(1-exp(-50*PD))/(1-exp(-50))))}

K = function(PD, LGD) {LGD*(dnorm(sqrt(1/(1-R))*qnorm(PD) + sqrt(R/(1-R))*qnorm(0.999)))}

K(0.1, 0.4)
```

When I run the code I get the following error;

```
R = function(PD) {(0.12*(1-exp(-50*PD))/(1-exp(-50)) + 0.24*(1-(1-exp(-50*PD))/(1-exp(-50))))}
```

> K = function(LGD, PD) {LGD*(dnorm(sqrt(1/(1-R))*qnorm(PD) + sqrt(R/(1-R))*qnorm(0.999)))}
>   K = function(PD, LGD) {LGD*(dnorm(sqrt(1/(1-R))*qnorm(PD) + sqrt(R/(1-R))*qnorm(0.999)))}
>   K(0.1, 0.4)
>   Error in 1 - R : non-numeric argument to binary operator'

Comment: You have to call the function: `R(PD)` Compare: `1-sqrt` vs. `1-sqrt(4)`

Comment: Thank you it is now working

Answer (score 0):

Your function `R` requires an argument, so you have to modify your `K` function by adding the `PD` argument to every `R` function call:

```
K <- function(PD, LGD) {
    LGD*(dnorm(sqrt(1/(1-R(PD)))*qnorm(PD) + sqrt(R(PD)/(1-R(PD)))*qnorm(0.999)))
}
```